# DURANDAL - Passing parameters to composition and modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, durandal

My goal is to show a **detailed** view of an item using Bootstrap modal mechanism in Durandal. Assume i have a viewmodel: 'itemdetail' and another viewmodel: 'items'. The modal element of Bootstrap is located on items.html but it is called from itemdetail.js in the viewAttached function.

I was able to figure out how to navigate to a detailed view of an item using the router (by passing the id 'myroute/:id') but i couldn't figure out how to compose it without the routing. I would expect something like that:

```
<div data-bind="compose: {model: viewmodels/myvm, activate:true, id:itemID}
```

I understand that i can use and observable and pass it some settings. But i don't know if the settings include my own parameters.

Eventualy i would like to inject this composition (the detailed description of the item) into a bootstrap modal and call it from itemdetails (attachedView).

Does it make any sense? is there a better way to do it?

thanks,
David

Answer (score 3):

I think it's more elegant and easiest to pass your data using twitter bootstrap modal call :

```
app.showModal('viewmodels/???', yourdataobject).then(function (result) {
            if (result) {

           }
);
```

Comment: This is the way I went. Works like a charm. To complete the answer a bit, the `yourdataobject` gets passed by durandal into the child viewModel's `activate` callback like this: `activate: function(yourdataobject) {}`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Just a little heads-up in case someone needs this like I did :-) -- showModal() has been changed to showDialog() in Durandal 2. Usage remains the same, tho.

Answer (score 1):

BTW i think this is an elegant solution.
I'm using  v2.0.1.

```
 <!-- ko compose: { model:'MyMODEL' , activationData:[YOUR_DATA] } -->
 <!-- /ko -->
....
function activate(YOUR_DATA){
    //Do something 

 }
```

Comment: thanks; this is actually on the docs page but there is no example and its not that well documentated http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to include parameters directly as part of composing a view/view model. Parameters are handled by the router and navigation, not by the composition process directly.

However, if the view model you want to compose is a singleton (like the Durandal ones) you can manually require it, set any properties on it (like itemId), and then let the composition occur normally.  The view model will then already have its itemId property set when the activate function is called.
Alternatively, depending on what you're trying to do, you could call the activate function manually and pass in your own "context" object.  In this  case, you'd probably want to set activate: false in your compose binding.

Not quite the same as getting it as an argument to the activate function, I know, but it might give a way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: hi thanks, I tried what I think was your solution (not sure i understood you correctly though): " compose:....activate:myObservable)" and then I transferred a json to myObservable in the parent module. However, the context in the activate function was undefined. So i am not sure i followed correctly. Could you please give example how to require parameter manually, not sure I got this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, although I am not sure that my solution is the most elegant there is, but it works just fine for me.

The first thing I did was placing the html for BOOTSTRAP modal on items.html (the view for the viewmodel that renders the items) like so:

```
<div id="itemDetails" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-abelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
       <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
     </div>
   <div class="modal-body" data-bind="compose: { model: 'viewmodels/itemdetail', activate: activateItemDetail }" >
    <!--  -->
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

Note that I placed my binding line inside modal-body

```
data-bind="compose: { model: 'viewmodels/itemdetail', activate: activateItemDetail }"
```

and note that i assigned the property activateItemDetail to "activate". activateItemDetail is assigned 'true' when the user clicks on the dom element that invokes the modal.activateItemDetail is subscribed to another property of Items viewmodel called itemId like so:

```
vm.itemId.subscribe(function(){
      this.activateItemDetail(true);
  }, vm);
```

So now we know that the detailed view model is activated only after we have received an id from the user.

Next, in itemdetail view model activation i placed the following code

```
 function activate(){
     //get the item id from the items - you need to require the items model
     var id = items.requestedItemId;
     //now you need to get the data from your service 
     dataService.getItemDetail(item, itemId),
     //now you call the modal 
     $('#itemdetail').modal.show();

 }
```

ONE LAST THING you need to do is to deactivate the itemdetail viewmodel when you are done. You can do that by data-bind deactivation function to the 'hidden' event of Bootstrap's modal like so:

```
data-bind="event: {hidden: closeItemDetails}"
```

and then you simply deactivate like so:

```
this.activateItemDetail(false);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

in durandal 2.0 you should use activationData object to pass parameters:

`composition.compose(wrapper, {mode:..., view:..., activationData : {id:}}, context`

in your case :
`compose:{..., activationData:{itemId:X}}`

Comment: Can activationData be used in durandal 1.1 version ?

Comment: I don't remember clearly but you could just pass the parameters along composition parameters without wrapping them in side `activationData`

Comment: I solved the problem and posted the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039275/activationdata-not-getting-passed-in-durandal?noredirect=1#comment38995482_25039275