# activationData not getting passed in durandal

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, hottowel

I am using durandal version 1.1. From compose binding I am passing some extra parameters through activationData. But the child viewmodel does not get the value. It is always received as undefined in the activate method.

```
<div data-bind="compose: {
                        model: 'testmodel',
                        activationData: {data : 10},
                            activate: true

                        }">

</div>
```

The activate method looks like:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/logger', 'services/datacontext', 'config'], function (app, system, router, logger, Datacontext, config) {

var testmodel= function () {

    var vm = this;

    vm.activate = function (activationData) {
        alert(activationData);
        logger.log('View Activated',
               null, 'test', true);
    };
 };
 return testmodel;

});
```

Also added activate to prototype but that does not work as well:

```
 define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/logger', 'services/datacontext', 'config'], function (app, system, router, logger, Datacontext, config) {

var testmodel= function () {

    var vm = this;
};
testmodel.prototype.activate = function (activationData) {
        alert(activationData);
        logger.log('View Activated',
               null, 'test', true);
};

 return testmodel;

});
```

Comment: Yes, it is available in 2.1. [Reference](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html).

Comment: @Brett In durandal 1.1, when I see the viewModel.js file, I see that activationData is passed to the activate method. It means it is available in 1.1 ? Am I correct ?

Comment: Just a guess, but I think the way you are using it is wrong. It might be that it does not understand `{ data: 10 }` literally. Have you tried a value like `10` or tried putting single-quotes around the expression?

Comment: @Brett Yes, I tried passing activationData : [10] / activationData : 10. That does not help.

Comment: It might help to see the `activate` code of your `testmodel.js`.

Comment: I have added the method.

Comment: @user2585299 Where is `vm` coming from?  Should it possibly be `vm.prototype.activate`?  Or, if this is a singleton module, you would need to export `activate`.

Comment: @EricTaylor I have added the viewmodel that includes the activate method. vm is reference to this within it. Also I did not get how to export activate ?

Comment: @user2585299 Please take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23407776/3174746).  You need understand the difference between *singleton modules* and *instance modules*, which are rooted in general JavaScript techniques.  Dan Wahlin's [course](http://beta.pluralsight.com/courses/structuring-javascript) from Pluralsight is essential to understanding the difference

Comment: @EricTaylor Yes, I added the activate to prototype, but still the activationData is received as undefined. You can see that in my edited question.

Comment: @user2585299 Replace `activationData: {data: 10}` with simply this: `activationData: data`.  Then, on your viewModel, in the constructor function set up an instance variable like so: `data: {data: 10}`. Of course, you can always refactor into better-named variables, etc.  Let's just get this working for now.  If this doesn't work, I will need to see the entirety of your view and viewModel.  This is actually pretty trivial stuff that should simply work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I am using durandal 1.1 version. There is a **tryActivate** function in **composition.js** file which makes a function call as shown below:

```
function tryActivate(settings, successCallback) {
    if (shouldPerformActivation(settings)) {
        viewModel.activator().activateItem(settings.model).then(function (success) {
            if (success) {
                successCallback();
            }
        });
    } else {
        successCallback();
    }
}
```

Only viewmodel parameter was passed to activateItem as seen above. I also passed the activationData parameter from there as below:

```
viewModel.activator().activateItem(settings.model,settings.activationData).then(function (success) {
            if (success) {
                successCallback();
            }
        });
```

Now, the activate method in testmodel as seen in the question gets the value 10 in activationData parameter.